# extracting data from Object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, api, object

I have this code to fetch data from remote API which returns folowing RAW data

```
{"BTC":0.00002067,"USDT":1,"DOGE":21.53}
```

and/or following Object

```
stdClass Object ( [BTC] => 2.056E-5 [USDT] => 1 [DOGE] => 21.52
```

I am using this code

```
  $url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=USD&tsyms=BTC,USDT,DOGE';
  $data = file_get_contents($url);
  $priceInfo = json_decode($data);

  foreach ($priceInfo as $val){
  echo "<br>--> ".$val;
  }
```

which returns this

```
--> 2.056E-5
--> 1
--> 21.52
```

but I would have this result

```
--> BTC 0.00002067
--> USDT 1
--> DOGE 21.52
```

How can reach this result ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly's anwer is correct, but I suggest using `json_decode($data, true)`, which will decode the JSON as an associative array, versus an object. That will make more sense with the `foreach` loop, along with allowing usage with any of PHP's array functions.

Comment: @kfriend Not necessary, as an object can also have its properties looped over using a foreach just like an array and as this is a properties only object its fairly academic

Comment: @RiggsFolly, you're correct that technically the `foreach` works in this example, but that was not my point. My point was that converting it to an associative array would likely be more useful for the OP. Obviously that could change depending on the eventual context the data is used in. In the wild, using an object in this fashion is not typical, and so again, an associative array is the better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then use the extended form of foreach

```
foreach ($priceInfo as $key => $val){
  echo "<br>--> $key " . sprintf('%0.8f', $val);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , do you know why PHP returns me BTC 2.06E-5 instead of  BTC 0.00002067 ?

Comment: That should sort that